# SQLAlchemy: Maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a python object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Here are the 4 tables that I created using sqlalchemy.orm

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass, Session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import VARCHAR, INTEGER, NUMERIC

DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://postgres:0000@localhost:5432/store'

engine = create_engine(url = DATABASE_URL)
Session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
session = Session()

class Base(DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass):
    pass

class User(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'user'
   id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, init=False)
   username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(VARCHAR, unique=True)

   purchases: Mapped[list['Purchase']] = relationship(back_populates= 'user', init=False, cascade='all, delete')

class Manufacturer(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'manufacturer'
   id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, init=False)
   name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(VARCHAR)
   
   products: Mapped[list['Product']] = relationship(back_populates='manufacturer', init=False)


class Product(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'product'
   id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, init=False)
   name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(VARCHAR, index=True)
   manufacturer_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('manufacturer.id'), init=False)

   manufacturer: Mapped['Manufacturer'] = relationship(back_populates='products')
   purchases: Mapped[list['Purchase']] = relationship(back_populates= 'product', init=False)


class Purchase(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'purchase'
   id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, init=False)
   user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'), init=False)
   product_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('product.id'), init=False)
   cost: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(NUMERIC(10, 2), index=True)

   
   user: Mapped['User'] = relationship(back_populates='purchases')
   product: Mapped['Product'] = relationship(back_populates='purchases')
```

This is the sequence in which I am running it

```
def create_user():
    u = User(username = 'john')
    session.add(u)
    session.commit()

def create_manufacturer():
    m = Manufacturer(name='apple')
    session.add(m)
    session.commit()

def create_product():
    m = session.query(Manufacturer).where(Manufacturer.id == 1).first()
    p = Product(name='iphone', manufacturer=m)
    session.add(p)
    session.commit()

def create_purchase():
    p = session.query(Product).where(Product.id == 1).first()
    u = session.query(User).where(User.id == 1).first()
    pur = Purchase(cost = 999.99, product=p, user = u)
    session.add(pur)
    session.commit()

def show_user_purchases():
    user = session.query(User).where(User.id == 1).first()
    print(user.purchases)

Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind = engine)
create_user()
create_manufacturer()
create_product()
create_purchase()
show_user_purchases()
```

Base on the output:

[Purchase(id=1, user_id=1, product_id=1, cost=Decimal('999.99'), user=User(id=1, username='john', purchases=[...]), product=Product(id=1, name='iphone', manufacturer_id=1, manufacturer=Manufacturer(id=1, name='apple', products=[...]), purchases=[...]))]

I suspect there is an infinite loop going on between user and purchases. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use `repr=False` on attributes to omit it from the representation. Or use it on the class to define a custom `__repr__` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the dataclass integration, you'd want to set `repr=False` on
relationship attributes. Or your purchase will show user, which will show
purchases and so on, resulting in a loop (but I think the actual implementation
will show a `...` if a loop is detected and omit the rest). Or you can use it
(`repr=False`) on the class and define your own `__repr__` method instead of
getting it generated from the dataclass.

Updated code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, Integer, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import (DeclarativeBase, Mapped, MappedAsDataclass,
                            mapped_column, relationship, sessionmaker)

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:test_password@localhost:5432/test_db"
engine = create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL,
)
Session = sessionmaker(
    bind=engine,
)


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, init=False)

    purchases: Mapped[list['Purchase']] = relationship(
        back_populates='user',
        init=False,
        cascade='all, delete',
        repr=False,
    )


class Manufacturer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'manufacturer'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, init=False)

    products: Mapped[list['Product']] = relationship(
        back_populates='manufacturer',
        init=False,
        repr=False,
    )


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, init=False)
    manufacturer_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('manufacturer.id'),
        init=False,
    )

    manufacturer: Mapped['Manufacturer'] = relationship(
        back_populates='products',
        repr=False,
    )
    purchases: Mapped[list['Purchase']] = relationship(
        back_populates='product',
        init=False,
        repr=False,
    )


class Purchase(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'purchase'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, init=False)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'), init=False)
    product_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('product.id'), init=False)

    user: Mapped['User'] = relationship(
        back_populates='purchases',
        repr=False,
    )
    product: Mapped['Product'] = relationship(
        back_populates='purchases',
        repr=False,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    with Session() as session:
        user = User()
        session.add(user)
        session.commit()

        manufacturer = Manufacturer()
        session.add(manufacturer)
        session.commit()

        product = Product(manufacturer=manufacturer)
        session.add(product)
        session.commit()

        purchase = Purchase(user=user, product=product)
        session.add(purchase)
        session.commit()

    with Session() as session:
        user = session.scalar(select(User))
        for purchase in user.purchases:
            print(purchase)
```

This will show:

```
Purchase(id=1, user_id=1, product_id=1)
```

Comment: posted the whole code